# When I compile my code it says error '{' expected in the 4th line where I have my class, but I have a '{' there

Tags: java

I am using java and having problem with my code. So for some reason when I compile my project on the 4th line it says error: '{' expected. resource says proj 2.java. Any help would be appreciated! thanks.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class proj 2 {


    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {
        BufferedReader dataIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

int a=0, b=0, c=0, d=0, f=0, totalNumber=0; 

stars();
System.out.println("Enter a list of exam scores from 0-100 ");
System.out.println("use a negative one if you're done with your list:");
stars();

for(int grade=0;grade>=0;totalNumber++)

{
    try
    {
    grade=Interger.parseInt(dataIn.readLine());
    if(grade>=90 && grade<=100)
    a++;
    else if (Grade>=80 && grade<=89)
        b++;
    else if (grade>=70 && grade>=79)
        c++;
    else if (grade>=60 && grade<=69)
        d++;
    else if (grade>=0 && grade<=59)
        f++;
    else if (grade>100)
{
    System.out.println("Invalid Grade");
    totalNumber--;
    }   
}

catch(NumberFormatException e)  
{
    System.out.println("Invalid input. Please enter your score in number form.");
    totalNumber--;
    continue;
    }   
}
System.out.println("");
System.out.println("Total number of grades: " +(totalNumber-1));
System.out.println("A grades: " + a);
System.out.println("B grades: " + b);
System.out.println("C grades: " + c);
System.out.println("D grades: " + d);
System.out.println("F grades: " + f);
}
public static void stars()
{
    System.out.println("**********************************************************************");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
class proj 2 {
```

to

```
class proj2 {
```

A class name can't have spaces.

Also change `Interger` to `Integer` and `Grade` to `grade`.

Comment: When I do that it says error: cannot find symbol in the 22nd and 25th line.

Comment: @MattJordan What symbol can't it find?

Comment: I suspect `Grade` and `Interger`.  I also suggest using an IDE which will highlight these errors.

Comment: I am not sure. It just says error: cannot find symbol. Then says 22nd and 25th line.
22 = grade = Interger.parseInt(dataIn.readLine());
25 =  else if (Grade>=80 && grade<=89)

Comment: @MattJordan Change `Interger` to `Integer` and `Grade` to `grade`.